# VBA: Transpose a Set range data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, range, transpose

My project involves copying data from files in a folder into one excel. The files in the folder have the data in rows and I need to data to be transposed to the one Excel (the DataBase Excel). I found some code that is very close to what I need and I am trying to modify that code to work for me. It look like i just need to modify the destrange in the code below, but I am unable to get any tweaks to work.

Full code can be found here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

What am I missing to transpose the data from Rows to columns???

```
 If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceCcount = sourceRange.Columns.Count

                If Cnum + SourceCcount >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough columns in the sheet"
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    'Copy the file name in the first row
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(1, Cnum). _
                                Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                    End With

                    'Set the destrange
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Cells(2, Cnum)
                    'Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & 1)

                    'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
                        'destrange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    Cnum = Cnum + SourceCcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that de Bruin is not using the Copy method.  Try this *(not tested)*

```
'Set the destrange
                Set destrange = BaseWks.Cells(2, Cnum)
                'Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & 1)

                'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                With SourceRange

                 'NOTE we reverse the rows and columns
                    Set destrange = destrange. _
                                    Resize(.Columns.count, .Rows.count)
                End With

               'NOTE we transpose the SourceRange.  If SourceRange has a huge number of rows, might have to do this manually.

                destrange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRange.Value)
```

Comment: "destrange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRange.Value)" This did not give me an error message, but it put the first value in each row for the same number of rows. Example: I had 20 rows I wanted Transposed with "Test Area" in row one. In the new excel (destrange) A2:A21 all had "Test Area".

Comment: @MichaelKapp Is your comment a question or a statement?

Comment: A question. the Transpose function did not work as (I) expected. I need help getting it work correctly. Also you Say that de Bruin is not using the copy method. What method is he using? Not sure what to google..

Comment: @MichaelKapp Sorry.

Comment: @MichaelKapp  Where in de Bruin's code do you see .Copy?  He uses it when he also wants to copy formats, but not just for values.  I suggest you take a look at [Chip Pearson's website](www.cpearson.com) and learn about reading and writing arrays to/from a worksheet, as well as much other useful information.  If the `Transpose` is not working as you expect, then there's something about your data, or your expectations, that I don't understand from your question.

Comment: @MichaelKapp With you editing your comments, I've got some stuff out of order.  Looking now at your first comment, to which I responded before you edited it to explain the problem, it is possible that you and Excel understand transpose differently.  You need to edit your original question to show the data you are copying; the expected results; and the actual results after "transposing", in order for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Ron,
The solution you posted was correct. I had a typo when I was updating my code.
Note. I also had to make other updates like creating and swapping out Cnum for Rnum so the data would get added by rows instead of columns. That you for your time and quick response. 
I wasn't trying to insist that de Bruin was using the copy method, I was trying to figure out the name of the method he used. I guess it does not really have a name. He is just using arrays to move data around.